# Extension Camera Not Found - Phonegap 3.0

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, blackberry-10

I'm using Phonegap 3 and am testing on a Blackberry 10 device. I cannot get the Camera to work. I added the Camera plugin but when I tap the button in the app to take a picture I get the error

```
'Failed because: Extension Camera not found.'
```

When I test in Ripple the errors I get on the console are

```
'Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined' when the page first loads
```

and

' ReferenceError: Camera is not defined ' when trying to take  a picture

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="default.app.id" version="1.0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets">
    <name>Webworks Application</name>
    <author>Your Name Here</author>
    <description>
       A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
    <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
    </license>
    <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home" />
    <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />
    <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
    <icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <rim:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/splash-1280x768.png" />
    <rim:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/splash-720x720.png" />
    <rim:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/splash-768x1280.png" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <rim:permissions>
        <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>record_audio</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit>
    </rim:permissions>
    <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus" value="NetworkStatus" />
</widget>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-role="header" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="canlist" data-role="listview">
        </ul>
        <a href="#newcan" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">New can</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
        <h2 class="offline">Offline Mode</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<div data-role="page" id="newcan">
    <div data-role="header" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="candetailcontent" data-role="content">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
        <p>Snapcan!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var candata = {cantitle:"", candetail:"", canlat:"",canlon:""};
var cantemplate = '<input type="text" name="cantitle" value="{{cantitle}}" placeholder="Can Title"/><textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="candetail" id="candetail" placeholder="Can Detail">{{candetail}}</textarea><input id="addphoto" type="button" data-icon="plus" value="Add a photo" /><img id="canimage" src="{{imagesource}}" /><div id="map">Map Placeholder</div><input id="savecan" type="button" data-theme= "a" value="Save Can"/>';
var lat,long;
 var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
$(document).on("pageinit", function(){
                                               $('#newcan').on('pagecreate', function(event){
                                                                  var html = Mustache.to_html(cantemplate, candata);
                                                                  $("#candetailcontent").html(html);
                                                                  });
                                               $("#newcan").on("pageshow", function(){
                                                                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
                                                                  });
                                               $("#addphoto").bind("tap", function(){
                                                                   var options = {sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI};
                                                                   navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess, onError, options);
                                                                   });
                                               });


    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
         pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Handle the online event
    //
    function onOnline() {
       $(".offline").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }

    function onOffline() {
        $(".offline").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

function onGeoSuccess(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            var currentposition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

            var mapoptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: currentposition,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapoptions);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentposition,
                    map: map
            });
        }

        function onCameraSuccess(imageURI){
            $('#canimage').attr("src", imageURI);
            $('#canimage').css("display","block");
        }   
function onGeoError(error){
    if(error==1){
    alert('Turn on Geolocation services');  
    }
}

function onCameraError(message){
    alert(message); 
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why can't I access the camera?

Answer (score 0):

please check if  >cordova.js  is in your www folder else specify the same name as of cordova.js for example `<script src="cordova3.0.js"></script>`